# Compare sum of number of words in string columns with value in another column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a spark DataFrame consisting of 3 columns: `text1`, `text2` and `number`.

I want to filter this DataFrame based on the following constraint:

```python
(len(text1)+len(text2))>number
```

where `len` returns the number of words in `text1` or in `text2`.

I tried the following:

```python
common_df = common_df.filter((len(common_df["text1"].str.split(" ")) +  len(common_df["text2"].str.split(" "))) > common_df["number"])
```

but it is not working. I get the following exception:

> ```python
> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
> ```

Here is a sample of my input:

```python
text1    text2     number
bla bla  bla no     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pyspark.sql.functions.length()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.length) returns the character length of a string. If you want to count the words, you can use [`split()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) and [`size()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size):

It looks like you're looking for:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, size, split
common_df.where(
    (size(split(col("text1"), "\s+")) + size(split(col("text2"), "\s+"))) > col("number")
).show()
```

First you split the strings on the pattern `\s+` which is any number of whitespace characters. Then you take the size of the resulting array.

You can also define a function if you're planning on calling this repeatedly:

```python
def numWords(column):
    return size(split(column, "\s+"))

common_df.where((numWords(col("text1")) + numWords(col("text2"))) > col("number")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `length` from `pyspark.sql.functions`:

```
common_df[(F.length('text1') + F.length('text2')) > common_df['number']]
```

Note that `[]` is a substitute for `filter()`.

Comment: length retrun the number of character in each column, Im looking to get the number of words

Comment: Then you can call the`size` function after `split` the columns.
e.g. `size(split(col("text1"), "\s+"))` will give you the number of  words in the column "text1"

Answer (score 1):

You are almost close, try this -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import length

common_df.filter("(length(text1) +  length(text2)) > number").show()
```

Comment: im length returns the number of character not the word's number

Comment: could you please add some sample data and expected output in your question for better understanding?